# how to check server at particular port in java in network?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I have a server running at a particular port in a network (WiFi). There can be multiple servers running on multiple IPs on that same port. I want to know all the IPs running servers. I am a beginner. How should I proceed, considering I want to do it in Java (Android)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know all the IP addresses concerned:

```
for (String ipAddress : ipAddresses)
{
    try (Socket socket new Socket(ipAddress, port))
    {
        System.out.println(ipAddress+":"+port+" is listening");
    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        System.out.println(ipAddress+":"+port+" connection failure: "+exc);
    }
}
```

E&OE